# How to reset ListView.Builder index

Tags: flutter

```
child: FutureBuilder(
     future: getTasks(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (task != null && task.tasks.length > 0) {
         return ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
           itemCount: task.tasks.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return task.tasks[index].start_date == selecteddate
                 ? TarefaCard(
                     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                     title: task.tasks[index].description,
                     howlong: task.tasks[index].howlong_str,
                     icon: Icon(icons[0]),
                     indice: index,
                     onPress: _setActiveTask )
                 : Container();
           },
         );
       } else {
         return Center(
           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         );
       }
 }),
```

This code when execute for the first time calls the API and 
loads my class named task with all the tasks from 15 days. 
The last 7 days, today and the next 7 days. This JSON file 
is sorted by date so I can make a list of all dates users
have in that period of time. So the first ones have the
older dates.

With those dates I create a ButtonMenu and the users can 
select which tasks they want to see by selecting a date.

When it's called the next time, the method getTasks() does not
call the API anymore, it just uses the JSON that was loaded before.

Unfortunately this code does not work all the time because
the value of index variable changes all the time and for my
benefit ListView.builder trying to be efficient does not
reset the index to 0 all the time.

Then this part of the code

```
return task.tasks[index].start_date == selecteddate
```

fails and does not show the task related to the selecteddate 
as it should.

Because the user browsed the file to the last date the index 
is high, now if he tries to see the first date the index is too
high and `[index].start_date` is not equal to  `selecteddate`

How could I reset this variable or my approach is totally wrong
and should be implemented totally different?

Comment: I don't understand how the index is related to you problem if you're just checking on the start date.

Comment: The tasks come ordered by date so I can build a list of distinct dates which exist for that user. I create a ButtonMenu with that list where the user select the date. As the list is ordered by date, so the lower the index the lower is the date. When they browse to the top of the list the index get higher. So if he select the first date that part of the code would find those dates at the begining of the list not close to the end. Made myself clear?

Comment: I suggest you do the filtering outside the itemBuilder, for example `var filteredTasks = tasks.where(task => task.start_date == selecteddate)` and then use filteredTasks in your ListView

Comment: It worked this way. Make this an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the `start_date` inside the itemBuilder, compute a `filteredTasks` and use it in your ListView:

```
var filteredTasks = tasks.where((task) => task.start_date == selecteddate)
```